# JS - перезапуск интервала

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, при загрузке страницы каждые 2 секунды обновляется элемент, нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку обновление прекращалось на 10 секунд, а потом запускалось заново. Вот что есть:

```
var time = setInterval(function(){ live() }, 2000);

function live() {
    $('.live-line').load('request.php').fadeIn("slow");
}

function reloadTimer() {
    clearInterval(time);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var time = setInterval(function(){ live() }, 2000);
    }, 10000);
}
```

В первый раз при нажатии на кнопку все срабатывает, но на последующие нажатия интервал не останавливается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Измените `reloadTimer()` на:

```
function reloadTimer() {
    clearInterval(time);
    setTimeout(function(){
        time = setInterval(function(){ live() }, 2000);
    }, 10000);
}
```

Таким образом вы будете менять ту, основную переменную вместо определения локальной (теряющейся сразу на выходе из функции).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, так и знал что в той строчке где-то ошибка.